# Importing only a chapter from a docx in Python

Tags: python-3.x, docx

I am trying to import only one or maybe two Chapters of my Word document.

Is there a way to just use the Chapter's name when I am importing the file and get that specific part?

I have tried everything that I could, but I still do not know how to import from a file with condition.
The best that I could come up with was just importing the whole file and creating a dictionary then look for the words that the chapter starts and ends with.
My importing file is the following:

```
import docx2txt
text = docx2txt.process("Example.docx")
text
```

Comment: That is probably the best you can do. You can also try do decode the formatting to recognize the chapter headers, assuming they are properly formatted.